# Git : Pull changes from remote branch without committing locally and finally push local changes to same branch

Tags: git

My team is working on a branch of the main git repo. I'm new to the team. I've cloned the repo and made some changes on the same branch locally. Now other team members have made several commits to the branch. Whenever such commits are made I want to pull them without making a commit locally and then push my changes to the remote branch.

I read several answers like using git stash and git rebase but I'm confused (I lack the understanding of these commands properly). I'm looking for a proper set of commands for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stash your work by `git stash` after pull from remote you can easily apply stash and back your local changes with remote changes.